# rounding to one decimal woes...

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

I have a problem with rounding --- I have seen [How do I get \pgfmathparse to create value rounded to one decimal place?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131982/how-do-i-get-pgfmathparse-to-create-value-rounded-to-one-decimal-place) but still I can't obtain the result I need.

See this MWE:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{venturis}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}

\newlength\caph\newlength\xlen%
\newcommand*{\prlen}[1]{%
   % round to 1 digit:
    \pgfmathparse{round(10*#1)/10.0}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=1}
    \pgfmathresult
   % \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
}
%
\newcommand{\showlengths}{%
\setlength{\caph}{\heightof{A}}%
\setlength{\xlen}{1ex}%
{\ttfamily
Caph: \prlen{\caph} \the\caph \par
X-He: \prlen{\xlen} \the\xlen \par
\medskip
}
}

\begin{document}

\librebaskerville\fontsize{100pt}{120pt}\selectfont
\showlengths

\fontfamily{yvtj}\fontsize{100pt}{120pt}\selectfont
\showlengths

\fontfamily{yvtd}\fontsize{100pt}{120pt}\selectfont
\showlengths

\fontfamily{lmr}\fontsize{100pt}{120pt}\selectfont
\showlengths

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: output]

...and you can see the loss of precision in the division by ten biting me sometime. If I change the definition of `\prlen` to use `\pgfmathprintnumber`, like this:

```
\newcommand*{\prlen}[1]{%
   % round to 1 digit:
    \pgfmathparse{round(10*#1)/10.0}%
    %\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=1}
    %\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
}
```

I have this, which prints things in math font:

[image: New output]

Is there a way to have a correct rounding but using the normal font I am using outside, like in the first case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\pgfmathprintnumber` uses math mode for this.

I suggest changing the definition of `\prlen`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\prlen}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round(\dim_to_fp:n { #1 }, 1) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

[image]

If you want one decimal digit even if zero, you can do

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\prlen}{m}{%
  \num[
    detect-all,
    round-integer-to-decimal,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=1,
  ]{\fp_eval:n { \dim_to_fp:n #1 }}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect. If only it printed 53.0 instead of 53... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Your wish is my command!